# aws s3 : image does not display

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I successfully upload image and also can get the imaget as Json forma but when it come to display on the browser it does not show up. Read about the base64 I used that but I could not display it here is my code

```
require("dotenv/config");

const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const { v4: uuid } = require("uuid");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
});

const storage = multer.memoryStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, "");
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage }).single("image");

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {

  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: "d19946bd-5e6f-4d7f-977d-db911323d67a.jpg",
    // Range: "bytes=0-9",
  };

  s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
 
    res.status(200).send(data);
  });
});
```

I try to use the encodedbase64 with this approach but it doesnt work it shows `E:\projects\aws projects\Node-upload-s3\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:31
throw err;
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined`

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  
  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: "d19946bd-5e6f-4d7f-977d-db911323d67a.jpg",
    // Range: "bytes=0-9",
  };

  
  const encode = (data) => {
    const str = data.reduce((a, b) => {
      return a + String.fromCharCode(b);
    }, "");
    return btoa(str).replace(/.{76}(?=.)/g, "$&\n");
  };
  s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    let image =
      "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64," + encode(data.body) + "'" + "/>";
    let startHTML = "<html><body><body/>";
    let endHTML = "</body></html>";
    let html = startHTML + image + endHTML;
    res.status(200).send(html);
  });
});
```

how can I display my image. could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending response as a JSON from node. Try to send **response as a file** and integrate it from Front-end.

Try this below code which sets headers of response

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename= d19946bd-5e6f-4d7f-977d-db911323d67a.jpg')
res.status(200).send(data.Body);
```

Comment: yeah I able to download the image now but I want it to display on the page rather than downloading to my photo gallery.

Comment: Give this API URL in the src attribute of your element.